# Replace first column first row to string 'date' in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv file and I have insert current date in the first column.

My code is here:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Paramter_Generation/LTERaw/'+date+'/ENodeBAlgoSwitch_1.csv',header=None,low_memory=False

  df.insert(0,'Date',date)
  df.to_csv('C:/Paramter_Generation/LTERaw/'+date+'/ENodeBAlgoSwitch_1.csv',header=None,index= False)
```

The dataframe is here:

```
  1     20180222  ne_name             handover_algo_switch   
  0     20180222      001  1111000000101000000001000000000   
  2     20180222      002  1111000000101000000001000000000   
  3     20180222      003  1111000000101000000001000000000
```

Now I want to change the first column first row '20180222' to string 'date'.

I know following code can change the first column first row to the string 'date':

```
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df.to_csv('C:/Paramter_Generation/LTERaw/'+date+'/'+names+'')
```

But after execute that, the column ne_name '001','002','003' will be replace to '1','2','3.'
I don't want to change other colume property.

Can anyne have idea how to  change the first column first row '20180222' to string 'date' and do not change other column property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems need:

```
f = 'C:/Paramter_Generation/LTERaw/'+date+'/ENodeBAlgoSwitch_1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'ne_name':str})
df.index = date

df.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: @EdwinCheng - I am confused, can you check answer?

Comment: It seems not work. Actually, I just need to change first column of first row from'2018022' to 'date'. Is any comment?

Comment: @EdwinCheng - How working `df.insert(0,'date',date)` ?

Comment: it will add one more column like that:                                                                                         
20180222 20180222 ne_name handover_algo_switch
20180222 20180222 001 1.111E+30

Comment: Or I have idea. Can you send me first 5 rows of your file to my email in my profile, if data not confidental? Because it seems some data problem.

Comment: date 0 1
20180222 ne_name handover_algo_switch
20180222 001' 1.111E+30                    After omit head=None, the date is add in the index

Comment: OK, can you provide your mail?

Comment: Is It jozefeg@gmail.com?  I have sent mail to you

Comment: I understand now, need `df.columns = ['date'] + df.columns[1:].tolist()`

Comment: The date will install in index. not header.                                                     
           date        1                                2  \
0     20180222  ne_name             handover_algo_switch

Comment: @EdwinCheng - I sent you email with solution, please check it.